# Invoking a standalone method from bytebuddy based java agent

Tags: java, byte-buddy, javaagents, jvm-bytecode

Lets say there is a method

```
public int getSize() {
return 3;
}
```

No other method calls this method in the java code.

I have written a java agent using bytebuddy, but AFAIK it only gives the capability to intercept a method call. Hence i can not intercept the method and capture the return value.

From my java agent, I want to scan all the methods with a annotation and call them. what are the ways to do this?

Comment: Use Reflection?

Comment: yes, that would be another way. I was seeing if we can do using bytebuddy iteself.

Comment: I'd need more context to answer this question. You are trying to call a method from another intercepted method? (`MethodCall`) Or are you trying to intercept the method? This should then be possible using the `AgentBuilder` API.

Comment: You are trying to call a method from another intercepted method? >> `no`, are you trying to intercept the method >> `no`. I am invoking this method from java agent in another thread. the use case is to implement gauge functionality, basically on a fixed interval call this method and capture the return value.

Comment: When you have a `Method` object, to read its annotations, you can also invoke it using the intuitively named method `invoke`. Why do you think you have to use bytebuddy?

Comment: because we are already using bytebuddy to develop a java agent, and this is the only missing piece which i am not able to figure out.

Comment: You “are already using” a `Method` (to read its annotations), so “the only missing piece” is to call invoke on it. It’s not clear why you want to bring in Bytebuddy at all costs; Bytebuddy is not a tool to invoke methods, it’s a tool to generate code.